# Clean, standard method for referencing local files in a project-based IDE (such as Eclipse or Visual Studio)?

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio, ide, standards

Recently I've begun taking advantage of the features offered by using robust IDEs, particularly the debugger and autocomplete found in Eclipse Juno and Visual Studio 2012.

However, many of my projects deal with lots of local files; for game projects I have custom content files, for data mining I have lots of data files that need to be referenced from a set of Python scripts, etc.

My issue is that storing these files within the project structure of the IDE seems hacky somehow (also, the IDEs tend to require a single entry point, which isn't so cool for working with data via a suite of scripts). The only other option I've found, using absolute paths relative to the drive, results in less-than-generalizable code.

My question: is there a good, clean method for referencing local data files (text files, XML, images, etc.) while still taking advantage of the features of a heavyweight IDE?

It seems there are ways such as "debug in directory" and "local reference folder" systems, but I'm wondering if there's some general way people deal with this.

Thank you for any information or suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

As for me, I'm always just either:

- storing files in the project dir, and using a versioning system (svn, git) exclude those and only include the directories they're in
- symlink the files, or whole directories, depending on the structure, into the project ; if you use relative symlinks instead of absolute ones, it makes it pretty easy for multiple people to have different files/content while still working on the same project over one repository. As it seems you're using windows (afaik visual-studio is windows only?), I think that newer windows versions should support symlinks as well, up from vista as far as I remember.

Edit: quick google search led me to: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link